# Codename one container.revalidate() IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown sometimes

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, runnable, codenameone

I've met such a problem. I'm getting IndexOutOfBoundsException when I'm calling .revalidate on container.

I have a Runnable class, which increases or decreases margin of component. I'm using it to make kind of drawer animation. Everything, except this exception, works perfectly. Ans the exception is thrown randomly. I can run "animation" method several times before I get this exception logged to the console.

And after that exception app is working fine. Only container is shown incorrect.

Here's error log:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.getComponentAt(Container.java:1083)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1054)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1043)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1056)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1043)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1056)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1043)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1056)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1043)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.revalidate(Container.java:835)
at util.classes.AnimationRunnable.run(AnimationRunnable.java:75)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why can it be? What can be the problem?

Thank you!

UPD:
Here's my runnable class:

Removed needless code:

```
public class AnimationRunnable implements Runnable {
private float marginFrom = 0;
private float marginTo = 0;
private Container bottomContainer;
private int screenHeight;

public AnimationRunnable(Container bottomContainer, int screenHeight, float marginFrom, float marginTo) {
    this.marginFrom = marginFrom;
    this.marginTo = marginTo;
    this.bottomContainer = bottomContainer;
    this.screenHeight = screenHeight;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    boolean finished = false;
    boolean directionUp = marginFrom > marginTo; // true = up; false = down
    Container parent = bottomContainer.getParent();

    while (!finished) {
    // if distance between current margin and destination margin is < 10, finish
        if (Math.abs(marginFrom - marginTo) < 10) {
            finished = true;
        } else {
            // if container size is increasing
            if (directionUp) {
                // if current margin is less than destination margin
                if (marginFrom <= marginTo) {
                    marginFrom = marginTo;
                    finished = true;
                } else {
                // else - modify current margin to be closer to destination margin
                    marginFrom -= Math.ceil((marginFrom - marginTo) / 6);
                }
            } else {
                // if current margin is less than destination margin
                if (marginFrom >= marginTo) {
                    marginFrom = marginTo;
                    finished = true;
                } else {
                // else - modify current margin to be closer to destination margin
                    marginFrom += Math.ceil((marginTo - marginFrom) / 6);
                }
            }
        }

        // Setting style to container (in case if container's current style is changed)
        Style defaultStyle = bottomContainer.getStyle();
        bottomContainer.getStyle().setMargin(Component.TOP, Math.round(marginFrom));
        // Setting default style to all container states

        // HERE EXCEPTION IS THROWN
        // Revalidating either parent, or container itself
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.revalidate();
            parent.repaint();
        } else {
            bottomContainer.revalidate();
            bottomContainer.repaint();
        }

        try {
        // Wait 25ms to make animation smooth
            Thread.sleep(25);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // revalidate once more after loop is over
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.revalidate();
        parent.repaint();
    } else {
        bottomContainer.revalidate();
        bottomContainer.repaint();
    }
    return;
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

CallSerially doesn't show the animation, it just waits, and updates the UI, when animation runnable. But calling Display.geInstance().invokeAndBlock() with this animation runnable works as wanted without throwing exceptions.

Comment: Please show some code if you want help

Comment: Sure! Added my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing UI not on the EDT, which can cause issues and conflicts between the thread you are running and the EDT(Event Dispatch thread).

Comment: Is there solutions how to avoid these conflicts and still use separate thread to change UI?

Comment: Use callSerially when changing the UI. There is a developer guide section on that.